# catch 500s when proxying requests in mod_perl

Tags: apache, perl, mod-proxy, mod-perl

I have a mod_perl module that proxies requests to another server in certain situations.

e.g.

```
   if($something) {
            $r->proxyreq(1);
            $r->uri( ... other server .... );
            $r->args($args);

            $r->handler('proxy-server');
            return Apache2::Const::OK;
   }
```

Is there any way to catch http error codes (e.g. 500s) returned by this other server and implement fallback logic?

Answer (score 1):

`$r->handler('proxy-server');` means that Apache httpd server response phase takes mod_proxy (not mod_perl).

If you catch this mod_proxy processed HTTP return code, then you can write `PerlLogHandler` or `PerlClenaupHandler` module after response phase for catch it.

```
# PerlLogHandler Your::CatchStatusCode
package Your::CatchStatusCode;

use strict;
use warnings;

# If you use mod_perl1.
#use Apache;
#use Apache::Constants qw(DECLINED HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);

# mod_perl2
use Apache2::RequestRec;
use Apache2::Const -compile => qw(DECLINED HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);

sub handler {
    my $r = shift;
    my $code = $r->status();
    if ( $code == Apache2::Const::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR ) {
        ...
    }
    # return untruth (not OK) for running other logging phase module (e.g. mod_log_custom)
    return Apache2::Const::DECLINED;
}
1;
```

Or addition your written script to insert to `PerlClenaupHandler`.

```
use Apache2::RequestUtil; # for push_handler
use Apache2::Const -compile => qw(OK HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
if($something) {
        $r->proxyreq(1);
        $r->uri( ... other server .... );
        $r->args($args);

        $r->handler('proxy-server');
        $r->push_handler( PerlCleanupHandler => sub {
            my $r = shift;
            # ... the same as above ...
        } );
        return Apache2::Const::OK;
}
```

However `PerlLogHandler` and `PerlCleanupHandler` can not output response to HTTP client (in other word, you can not `$r->print()`) because after request phase.

Comment: thanks - great detail.   there's no way to catch the 500 and respond differently?   e.g. catch the first few bytes of the response,  if it's a 500 do something, otherwise stream through to client?

Comment: maybe i can open a 'curl',  read the first line for status and dispatch on that